Lift Coefficient question

I am making a RC Airplane, it has a wing profile as shown above. What might be the approx. lift coefficient of this? The wingspan is 80cm, what will the lift provided be by this wing at 65kmph ?

At which angle of attack? If it's at 0 deg (the way you drew it), the first part will push the wing down. For a flat plate we have some answers here; like this one

During take-off it will be at around 15-20 degrees AOA, how will the behavior be then?

at that angle of attack the lift coefficient will be about 0.8, the average value for separated flow.

And what if I increase the angle between the two parts to 170 deg?

I'd expect it to work better the other way around, i.e. with the profile flying to the right of your picture.
140° is way too low, the airflow will almost certainly detach by that corner. Values >170° should be considered. I'd start with 185° and then decrease it in small steps.
A relatively high pitch nose-down should be also expected.
Maybe you can replace the kink with a more or less continuous curvature plus a fully bent nose section to get something like the "KFm-5b" in this picture.

Oh, if I go ahead and increase the angle to about 170 degrees, using it in the same orientation as I posted, would there be a higher lift at around 10degrees AOA ?

Also, at 170 degrees, would it be more efficient than a flate plate? Also, I cannot get rid of the kink since I am using a very stiff foam, so is there any workaround or can you please suggest a better airfoil without smoothened edges?

If you use the same orientation as posted I fear you'll get more drag than lift. To be conservative I'd reverse the orientation, limit the short part to 10% of the chord and use 170° as angle between the two parts. A small bumb on the upper surface by the leading edge would also help with the transition of the boundary layer to turbulent. Afterwards you can play around with the geometry, but I'd use that one as basis.

I have a propulsion system which is a propeller which I believe can counteract the drag. please correct me if I am wrong. So what would the lift coefficient at my orientation, 170 degrees 10 deg AOA be ?

As @PeterKämpf already said, no more than 0.8

Oh, 0.8 is perfect! thanks

But why not a simpler flat plate then? Less drag, less pitching moment and less vibrations...

I just wanted to experiment with different simple wing shapes
